# Installing MSI through windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-installer, installation

I have a strange problem,

I have a `WPF application`. I have created a `windows installer` for this and installation will create application shortcut in user's start menu. I'm installing this MSI through `windows service`. Installation works fine through windows service but it doesnt create shortcut in start menu also i dont see this application under Programs and Features. But if i manually install this everything works fine. Any clue why this is happening ?

> Code to execute MSI

```
 Process installProcess = new Process();
                //Assign required properties
                installProcess.StartInfo.FileName = MSIEXEC;
                installProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                installProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                LogManager.Write("Process object is created");

                //Create new StringBuilder instance
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.Append(SYMBOL_SLASH);
                stringBuilder.Append(SYMBOL_INSTALL);
                stringBuilder.Append(installerPath);
                stringBuilder.Append(SYMBOL_QN);

                LogManager.Write("StringBuilder is created: " + stringBuilder.ToString());

                installProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = stringBuilder.ToString();
                installProcess.Start();
```

Comment: Just a question ... for the msi, you haven' kept any screens? Does the Service automatically install everything?

Comment: I'm doing a silent installation. So i dont see any screen.

Comment: Can you show the code in the service where you execute the msi?

Comment: Just added the piece of code which executes MSI within windows service

Comment: Using the shell changes anything?

Comment: What is the ALLUSERS property set to?

Comment: It has been set to FALSE for both Windows Service and WPF installers

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Your guess was correct. Once I set the InstallAllUsers property to true. It appears in the start menu and under program featurs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InstallAllUsers` property in for MSI was set to `false`. My windows service was running under  `Local System account` and my machine was logged in with `windows authentication` under `administrator account`. So when the installation happened it was assumed that MSI is installed by the user other than who has logged into the machine with windows authentication so it didnt not show up in the start menu and under Programs and Features.

It was not necessary for me to keep the InstallAllUsers to false so simply i made it true which solved my problem.